# MySQL - put rows as columns and columns as rows?

Tags: mysql

How can I transpose a row to a column in MySQL?

I've read some questions on this topic on StackOverflow, but I still have no idea how I can achieve the result that I want. I've also tried some code without success.

The following sample will hopefully make my desired result clear. I created a view named "summary_kcal" grouped by user-ID. It is composed as below:

```
+---------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| userid  |  LU  |  MA  |  ME  |  GIO |  VE  |  SA  | DO   | 
+---------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 1       | 1000 | 2000 | 1000 | 1500 | 2000 | 1000 | 1500 |
+---------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

I want to convert it to:

```
+---------+---------+
| userid  | 1       |
+---------+---------+
| LU      | 1000    | 
+---------+---------+
| MA      | 2000    | 
+---------+---------+
| ME      | 1000    |
+---------+---------+
| GIO     | 1500    |
+---------+---------+
| VE      | 2000    |
+---------+---------+
| SA      | 1000    |
+---------+---------+
| DO      | 1500    |
+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: @uueerdo looks more like unpivot, but really, so vague, who knows?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Ah, yeah, I see that now. I must have skimmed too fast, as I thought the first block was the desired format.

Answer (score 1):

You're usually better off doing this kind of transform client side, but if you really need to do it in the database....

```
SELECT "LU" AS userid, `LU` AS `1` WHERE userid = 1
UNION
SELECT "MA" AS userid, `MA` AS `1` WHERE userid = 1
UNION
SELECT "ME" AS userid, `ME` AS `1` WHERE userid = 1
UNION
SELECT "GIO" AS userid, `GIO` AS `1` WHERE userid = 1
UNION
SELECT "VE" AS userid, `VE` AS `1` WHERE userid = 1
UNION
SELECT "SA" AS userid, `SA` AS `1` WHERE userid = 1
UNION
SELECT "DO" AS userid, `DO` AS `1` WHERE userid = 1
```

*Note: You only actually need the aliases on the first query, just included for clarity and consistency.*

In the event you want multiple columns, one for each user row, this gets unmanageable rather quickly as each `XX AS # WHERE userid = #` ends up needing to be a separate subquery instead *(or a large unwieldy GROUP CONCAT query with conditional aggregation)*.